# mdadm cron job sends email that cron has run

Tags: email, cron, mdadm, raid1

I've got an Ubuntu 8.04 server using mdadm to create several RAID1 arrays. I created `/etc/cron.hourly/mdadm` as follows:

```
#! /bin/sh

set -e

mdadm --monitor /dev/md0 /dev/md3 /dev/md4 --oneshot
```

(Yes, the array numbers are not sequential, and I'm not using `--scan` beacuse I have a degraded array that may or may not have been used as swap and I can't delete, but I think that's a separate issue. If it's the underlying cause of this, I need to fix it.)

`mdadm` sends me email (configured in the `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`) on DegradedArray etc. events. **This is the desired behaviour**. What is not desired, and I can't work out, is why `cron` is sending me (relatively pointless) emails, via an alias in `/etc/aliases`:

```
From: root@<hostname> (Cron Daemon)
To: root@<hostname>
Subject: Cron <root@<hostname>>    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ANSI_X3.4-1968
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>
Message-Id: <id@hostname>
Date: Fri,  7 May 2010 13:17:01 +0930 (CST)

/etc/cron.hourly/mdadm:
mdadm: Monitor using email address "<root_alias@domain>" from config file
```

I've got a dozen other servers behaving correctly (`mdadm` sends email, `cron` doesnt') with identical `/etc/crontab` files:

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# <snip comments>

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
<snip anacron jobs>
```

Should I simply remove the `--report`, or is there something else in my `cron` config somewhere causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron will email when a job produces output on stdout or stderr.  redirecting these to /dev/null is the usual way of avoiding this.

The `--report` arguement to run-parts prints the script name before the job's output.  In this case it adds `/etc/cron.hourly/mdadm:` to your email ahead of the output from mdadm.  Removing it will shorten the emails by removing some useful information, but not prevent them being sent.

Comment: Ah, got it. Because I'm not using `--scan`, it prints the "using email address from config file" message. Thanks!